# convert from decimal to HEX in python

Tags: python

I have a simple task, I'm requesting for user input for a 16 digit HEX number, but if the user enters a decimal number I'd like to convert it for them.
  I have the code written to re-ask for the input if it's not 16 digit HEX, but I'd like to add in the conversion from Decimal to HEX, and then validate that it's a 16 digit HEX number.

I guess I just need a shove in the right direction for the conversion.

thanks all!

Comment: If the hex result has a leading zero you'll never be able to know that it's 16 digits.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Presumably he wants to reject decimals that would require leading 0's to take up all 16 digits. And if not, it's just a matter of checking `<= 16` instead of `== 16`.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between a decimal and hex input if none of the digits are greater than 9?  Can you give some example inputs and their types?  Do you want just a string representation of a hex number as the output?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the [`hex()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) builtin:

```
In [23]: hex(187)
Out[23]: '0xbb'

In [24]: hex(123456789)
Out[24]: '0x75bcd15'

In [25]: len(hex(123456789)[2:])
Out[25]: 7

In [26]: len(hex(123456789)) - 2
Out[26]: 7
```

It returns a string prefixed with `0x`, so you'll need to either slice off the first two characters or check that the length is 16 + 2.

Also, if your user's input isn't already an integer, you'd need to convert it. Here's how I'd write the whole thing:

```
def your_function(dec, length=16):
    try:
        # Converts the string into an integer
        # If dec is already an integer, it won't throw any errors
        n = int(dec)

        return len(hex(n)[:2]) == length
    except ValueError:
        # int(dec) raised the error. It's not a number.
        return False
```

Comment: `decimal` is the name of a stdlib class (which is why SO blued it), so may be slightly confusing as the name of your parameter.

Comment: @abarnert: I couldn't really think of a better name. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe something longer, like `decimal_numeral` or `decimal_string`? Kind of ugly and verbose, but it's clear and explicit. (In my own code, I would almost certainly use `dec` without thinking, and then wake up in the middle of the night with Forth nightmares where the symbol `dec` is ambiguous with the hex numeral `dec`…)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hex()` built-in:

```
def check_hex_length(decimal_number):
  hex_number = hex(decimal_number) # hex_number now contains your number as hex.
  return (len(hex_number) - 2) == 16
```

Comment: Since `decimal_number` is a string from some input function, you need one more step here.

Comment: Nope, you change types when you call the function, matey

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but calling your function with a string user input will raise a `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreter as an integer` (or the same thing with slightly different wording, in earlier Python).

Comment: So you call it as `check_hex_length(int(yourNumber))`

Comment: If you're suggesting that he should first `try` to call `int`, and then only if that succeeds call `check_hex_length`, so he can distinguish between the two problems (not decimal number, vs. is a decimal but doesn't translate to 16 digits in hex), that seems reasonable. But you should say so in the answer. The name of your function, and the wording of the OP's question, both make it sound like you're taking a decimal string, not an integer.

Comment: I can't convert 26.35 to hex :s